# Type Conversion Errors in Java

Tags: java

```
char c1 = (int) Math.random();
        
char c2 = (int) 99.0;
        
char c3 = (int) getDouble();
```

why the first and the third line give errors, but the second one doesn't?

implementaion of getDouble():

`public static double getDouble() { return 9.0; }`

Comment: How is `getDouble`implemented

Comment: The second is a constant, known to be in the range of `char`...

Comment: I edited the post.
The method only returns a double.

Answer (score 1):

In all three cases, you are assigning an expression of type `int` to a variable of type `char`. This needs a [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (since `int` is larger than `char`).

Let's see whether that is allowed in an [assignment context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2).

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)) of
> type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of
>   type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is
>   representable in the type of the variable.

Okay, it is only allowed if the expression is a [*constant expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29).

Excerpt from the definition of "constant expression":

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
> type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
> only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type, string literals, and text blocks
> - Casts to primitive types and casts to type `String`
> - [...]

Informally, constant expressions are expressions whose values can be computed at compile time.

Of the 3 expressions `(int)Math.random()`, `(int)99.0`, and `(int)getDouble()`, **only** `(int)99.0` is a constant expression. Without running the code, it is clear that `(int)99.0` always evaluates to the value 99. The other two expressions are not constant expressions **because they contain method calls**, which are not included in the list above.

It also just so happens that the value of `(int)99.0` fits in the range of `char` (0-65535). Therefore, a conversion from `int` to `char` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason the first line of code is giving an error is that the cast from double to char is not allowed in Java. The Math.random() method returns a double

   ```
   char c1 = (int) Math.random();`
   ```
2. Java allows narrowing primitive conversions, including the conversion from **double** to **char**, In this case, the double value 99.0 is explicitly cast to an int value, and then that int value is implicitly narrowed to a char type.

   ```
   char c2 = (int) 99.0;
   ```
3. Not sure what is getDouble() method is

Comment: getDouble() just retruns a double (9.0)

Comment: Shouldn't the first line convert the result of the random method to an int explicity and then the int value to char implicity?

Comment: In fact, the third line will not compile no matter *what* `getDouble` returns and *however* it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's because *99.0* is a *literal*.

*[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

> *"... A literal is the source code representation of a fixed value; literals are represented directly in your code without requiring computation. As shown below, it's possible to assign a literal to a variable of a primitive type:*
>
> *boolean result = true;*
>     *char capitalC = 'C';*
>     *byte b = 100;*
>     *short s = 10000;*
>     *int i = 100000; ...*
>
> *... A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d."*

It's similar to how the compiler will throw an error when you try to assign a value which is too large for the declared type.

```java
int value = 9876543210;
```

And, not when you assign a resolved value.

```java
public static double getDouble() { return 9876543210d; }
```

```java
int value = (int) getDouble();
```

Or even a cast resolution,

```java
int value = (int) 9876543210d;
```

Since it's a *literal*, the compiler figures it should provide a warning, to eliminate the bug.

```java
System.out.println(value);
```

Output

```
2147483647
```

The compiler can compute the *literal* without having to make any resolve, or additional understanding of enclosing code; it is the "literal" value.